# splitting dataframe with collated points in to individuals in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (.txt) which looks like this [where "dayX" = the day of death in a survival assay in fruitflies, the numbers beneath are the number of flies to die in that treatment combination on that day, X or A are treaments, m & f are also treatments, the first number is the line, the second number is the block]

```
    line    day1    day2    day3    day4    day5
1   Xm1.1   0   0   0   2   0
2   Xm1.2   0   0   1   0   0
3   Xm2.1   1   1   0   0   0
4   Xm2.2   0   0   0   3   1
5   Xf1.1   0   3   0   0   1
6   Xf1.2   0   0   1   0   0
7   Xf2.1   2   0   2   0   0
8   Xf2.2   1   0   1   0   0
9   Am1.1   0   0   0   0   2
10  Am1.2   0   0   1   0   0
11  Am2.1   0   2   0   0   1
12  Am2.2   0   2   0   0   0
13  Af1.1   3   0   0   1   0
14  Af1.2   0   1   3   0   0
15  Af1.1   0   0   0   1   0
16  Af2.2   1   0   0   0   0
```

and want it to become this using R->

```
    XA  mf  line    block   individual  age
1   X   m   1   1   1   4
2   X   m   1   1   2   4
3   X   m   1   2   1   3
```

and so on...

the resulting dataframe collects the "age" value from the day the individual died, as scored in the upper dataframe, for example there were two flies that died on the 4th day (day4) in treatment Xm1.1 therefore R creates two rows, one containing information extracted regarding the first individual and thus being labelled as individual "1", then another row with the same information except labelled as individual "2".. if a 3rd individual died in the same treatment on day 5, there would be a third row which is the same as the above two rows except the "age" would be "5" and individual would be "3". When it moves on to the next treatment row, in this case Xm1.2, the first individual to die within that treatment set would be labelled as individual "1" (which in this case dies on day 3). In my example there is a total of 38 deaths, therefore I am trying to get R to build a df which is 38*6 (excl. headers).

is there a way to take my dataframe [the real version is approx 50*640 with approx 50 individuals per unique combination of X/A, m/f, line (1:40), block (1-4) so ~32000 individual deaths] to an end dataframe of 6*~32000 in an automated way?

both of these example dataframes can be built using this code if it helps you to try out solutions:

```
test<-data.frame(1:16);colnames(test)=("line")
test$line=c("Xm1.1","Xm1.2","Xm2.1","Xm2.2","Xf1.1","Xf1.2","Xf2.1","Xf2.2","Am1.1","Am1.2","Am2.1","Am2.2","Af1.1","Af1.2","Af2.1","Af2.2")
test$day1=rep(0,16);test$day2=rep(0,16);test$day3=rep(0,16);test$day4=rep(0,16);test$day5=rep(0,16)
test$day4[1]=2;test$day3[2]=1;test$day2[3]=1;test$day4[4]=3;test$day5[5]=1;
test$day3[6]=1;test$day1[7]=2;test$day1[8]=1;test$day5[9]=3;test$day3[10]=1;
test$day2[11]=2;test$day2[12]=2;test$day4[13]=1;test$day3[14]=3;test$day4[15]=1;
test$day1[16]=1;test$day3[7]=2;test$day3[8]=1;test$day2[5]=3;test$day1[3]=1;
test$day5[11]=1;test$day5[9]=2;test$day5[4]=1;test$day1[13]=3;test$day2[14]=1;

test2=data.frame(rep(1:3),rep(1:3),rep(1:3),rep(1:3),rep(1:3),rep(1:3))
colnames(test2)=c("XA","mf","line","block","individual","age")
test2$XA[1]="X";test2$mf[1]="m";test2$line[1]=1;test2$block[1]=1;test2$individual[1]=1;test2$age[1]=4;
test2$XA[2]="X";test2$mf[2]="m";test2$line[2]=1;test2$block[2]=1;test2$individual[2]=2;test2$age[2]=4;
test2$XA[3]="X";test2$mf[3]="m";test2$line[3]=1;test2$block[3]=2;test2$individual[3]=1;test2$age[3]=3;
```

*apologies for the awfully long way of making this dummy dataset, suffering from sleep deprivation and jetlag and haven't used R for months, if you run the code in R you will hopefully see better what I aim to do*

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

By Rg255:
Currently stuck at this derived from @Arun's answer (I have added the *strsplit **(as.character(dt$line)** , "" ))* section to get around one error)

```
df=read.table("C:\\Users\\...\\data.txt",header=T)
require(data.table)
head(df[1:20])
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, {dd <- unlist(.SD, use.names = FALSE); 
            list(individual = sequence(dd[dd>0]), 
                 age = rep(which(dd>0), dd[dd>0])
            )}, by=line]
out <- as.data.table(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(dt$line), ""))[, c(1:3,5)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
setnames(out, c("XA", "mf", "line", "block"))
out[, `:=`(line = as.numeric(line), block = as.numeric(block))]
out <- cbind(out, dt[, list(individual, age)])
```

Produces the following output:

```
     > df=read.table("C:\\Users\\..\\data.txt",header=T)
        > require(data.table)
        > head(df[1:20])
           line Day4 Day6 Day8 Day10 Day12 Day14 Day16 Day18 Day20 Day22 Day24 Day26 Day28 Day30 Day32 Day34 Day36 Day38 Day40
        1 Xm1.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     4     2
        2 Xm2.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     1     2     1     0     2     0
        3 Xm3.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1
        4 Xm4.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     2     3     8
        5 Xm5.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     3     3     3     6
        6 Xm6.1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1


> dt <- as.data.table(df)
        > dt <- dt[, {dd <- unlist(.SD, use.names = FALSE); 
        +             list(individual = sequence(dd[dd>0]), 
        +                  age = rep(which(dd>0), dd[dd>0])
        +             )}, by=line]
        > out <- as.data.table(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(dt$line), ""))[, c(1:3,5)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

        Warning message:
            In function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
              number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)


    > setnames(out, c("XA", "mf", "line", "block"))
        > out[, `:=`(line = as.numeric(line), block = as.numeric(block))]


    Error in `[.data.table`(out, , `:=`(line = as.numeric(line), block = as.numeric(block))) : 
          LHS of := must be a single column name, when with=TRUE. When with=FALSE the LHS may be a vector of column names or positions.
        In addition: Warning message:
        In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion


    > out <- cbind(out, dt[, list(individual, age)])
        >
```

Comment: Could you link me to the file? It'd be much easier to debug.

Comment: @Arun here is a link http://projectevomap.yolasite.com/temp-file-page.php let me know when you have downloaded it so I can take it off

Comment: I've downloaded it. I think I know what the problem is. I'll make an edit soon.

Comment: I've edited the answer and it works for the file you gave me on my R session (on a mac). I hope there's no other issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a `data.table` solution. The `line` column must have unique values.

```
require(data.table)
df <- read.table("data.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, {dd <- unlist(.SD, use.names = FALSE); 
                list(individual = sequence(dd[dd>0]), 
                age = rep(which(dd>0), dd[dd>0])
                )}, by=line]
out <- as.data.table(data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
        strsplit(gsub("([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]])([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)$", 
        "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", dt$line), " ")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
setnames(out, c("XA", "mf", "line", "block"))
out[, `:=`(line = as.numeric(line), block = as.numeric(block))]
out <- cbind(out, dt[, list(individual, age)])
```

This works on your `data.txt` file.